# Does Realm executeTransactionAsync close the instance

Tags: android, realm

The title says it all.  I've done some searching but haven't found anything concrete.

Do I need to call realm.close after doing realm.executeTransactionAsync or does the async transaction handle that?

Thank you

EDIT:  Per EpidPandaForce, executeTransactionAsync closes the background realm instance when complete.

But what is the proper way to close the realm instance if executeTransactionAsync is called from the UI thread?  In the transactions onSuccess/onFailure?

Comment: Async transaction closes the **background** Realm instance.

Comment: dude... don't you ever sleep?  :)

Comment: if I'm calling executeTransactionAsync, what's the proper way to close the realm?  I'll add that question to the OP

Comment: I do sleep but not at 3 PM :p as for the UI thread Realm that initiates the request, that's totally up to you (and where you opened it in the first place)

Comment: I don't want to close it before the transaction completes. Assuming I need to close it right after, what's the safest way?

Comment: Manually closing it in `onSuccess()` *and* `onError()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem like you're looking for the following scenario.

```
public void doWrite(MyObject obj) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); 
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            bgRealm.insert(obj); // assuming obj is unmanaged
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            realm.close();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            realm.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Im still getting the error "Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created." in OnError, any ideas?

Comment: That means you're still posting live Realm objects between threads and you should stop doing that

Comment: thanks, everything is within the executeTransactionAsync so shouldnt it be ok?

Comment: That depends on where you got the objects tht you are trying to use inside executeTransactionAsync

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin

```
fun doWrite(obj: RealmObject) {
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        realm.executeTransactionAsync({ bgRealm ->
            bgRealm.insert(obj) // assuming obj is unmanaged
        }, { realm.close() }, { realm.close() })
    }
```